# Can I use this touchscreen with my ESP32 controller?

Tags: touchscreen, esp32, micropython

I have an old 7" touchscreen which I originally bought for my Raspberry Pi 3B, but have recently started exploring MicroPython on ESP32 controllers. Long story short, seeing as how the ESP32 controller I am using has a built-in OLED display on I2C, I was wondering if it wouldn't be possible to drive my 7" touch screen from it as well? Seeing as how it has both the ribbon cable AND I2C contacts? Or am I wrong?

[Screen](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-touch-display/)
[Controller](https://heltec.org/project/wifi-lora-32/)

Comment: cant you read the datasheet of that display and find out yourself?

Answer (score 2):

If touch functionality is possible to connect to ESP32, then I have doubts about screen (as a video output). I do not think that ESP32 has enough computational power and/ or memory for display.

Single color 128x64 OLED Frame Buffer requires 8KB of RAM. After micropython installed, user left roughly 100KB memory. 800*400 = 320k (even monocolor)